# Matlab: seqlogo with uniform plot column heights

Tags: matlab, statistics, charts, probability, bioinformatics

In Matlab, I want to make a [seqlogo plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/seqlogo.html) of an amino acid sequence profile. But instead of scaling the heights of the plot columns by entropy, I want all the columns to be the same height.

I'm in the process of modifying the code from the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526714/changing-the-x-axis-of-seqlogo-figures-in-matlab), but I wonder if there is a parameter to seqlogo or some other function that I have missed that will make the column heights uniform.

Alternatively, is there a statistical transformation I can apply to the sequence profile to hack the desired output? (column heights uniform, height of each letter linearly proportion to 
its probability in the seqprofile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way around this problem is to directly modify the code for the [Bioinformatics Toolbox function SEQLOGO](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/seqlogo.html) (if possible). In R2010b, you can do:

```
edit seqlogo
```

And the code for the function will be shown in the editor. Next, find the following lines (lines 267-284) and either comment them out or remove them entirely:

```
S_before = log2(nSymbols);
freqM(freqM == 0) = 1; % log2(1) = 0

% The uncertainty after the input at each position
S_after = -sum(log2(freqM).*freqM, 1);

if corrError
    % The number of sequences correction factor
    e_corr = (nSymbols -1)/(2* log(2) * numSeq);
    R = S_before - (S_after + e_corr);
else
    R = S_before - S_after;
end

nPos = (endPos - startPos) + 1;
for i =1:nPos
    wtM(:, i) = wtM(:, i) * R(i);
end
```

Then put this line in their place:

```
wtM = bsxfun(@times,wtM,log2(nSymbols)./sum(wtM));
```

You will probably want to save the file under a new name, like `seqlogo_norm.m`, so you can still use the original unmodified [SEQLOGO](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/seqlogo.html) function. Now you can create sequence profile plots with all the columns normalized to the same height. For example:

```
S = {'LSGGQRQRVAIARALAL',...      %# Sample amino acid sequence
     'LSGGEKQRVAIARALMN',...
     'LSGGQIQRVLLARALAA',...
     'LSGGERRRLEIACVLAL',...
     'FSGGEKKKNELWQMLAL',...
     'LSGGERRRLEIACVLAL'};
seqlogo_norm(S,'alphabet','aa');  %# Use the modified SEQLOGO function
```

[image: normalized sequence profile]

**OLD ANSWER:**

I'm not sure how to transform the sequence profile information to get the desired output from the [Bioinformatics Toolbox function SEQLOGO](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/seqlogo.html), but I can show you how to modify the alternative `seqlogo_new.m` that I wrote for [my answer to the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526714/changing-the-x-axis-of-seqlogo-figures-in-matlab/2546777#2546777) you linked to. If you change the line that initializes `bitValues` from this:

```
bitValues = W{2};
```

to this:

```
bitValues = bsxfun(@rdivide,W{2},sum(W{2}));
```

Then you should get each column scaled to a height of 1. For example:

```
S = {'ATTATAGCAAACTA',...  %# Sample sequence
     'AACATGCCAAAGTA',...
     'ATCATGCAAAAGGA'};
seqlogo_new(S);            %# After applying the above modification
```

[image: normalized sequence profile]

Comment: Thanks! But as I mentioned in my question, I am plotting an *amino acid* sequence, so I need more than just the four letters you provide.

Comment: @Jon: Ahh, I missed that. I'll take another stab at a more complete solution tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution, and for showing me how to edit library fns :)

Answer (score 1):

For now, my workaround is to generate a bunch of fake sequences that match the sequence profile, then feed those sequences to http://weblogo.berkeley.edu/logo.cgi . Here is the code to make the fake sequences:

```
function flatFakeSeqsFromPwm(pwm, letterOrder, nSeqsToGen, outFilename)
%translates a pwm into a bunch of fake seqs with the same probabilities
%for use with http://weblogo.berkeley.edu/

%pwm should be a 4xn or a 20xn position weight matrix. Each col must sum to 1
%letterOrder = e.g. 'ARNDCQEGHILKMFPSTWYV' for my data
%nSeqsToGen should be >= the # of pixels tall you plan to make your chart

[height windowWidth] = size(pwm);
assert(height == length(letterOrder));
assert(isequal(abs(1-sum(pwm)) < 1.0e-10, ones(1, windowWidth))); %assert all cols of pwm sum to 1.0

fd = fopen(outFilename, 'w');

for i = 0:nSeqsToGen-1
    for seqPos = 1:windowWidth
        acc = 0; %accumulator
        idx = 0;
        while i/nSeqsToGen >= acc
            idx = idx + 1;
            acc = acc + pwm(idx, seqPos);
        end
        fprintf(fd, '%s', letterOrder(idx));
    end
    fprintf(fd, '\n');
end

fclose(fd);
end
```